# Подключение phpmailer, почтовые адреса

Tags: php, phpmailer

Здравствуйте. К какому файлу обратиться через require, чтобы сработал автозагрузчик PHPmailer, не нашел в распакованной папке версии 6.0.2 (может это get_oauth_token.php?). Подключать вручную - боязно, может чего напортачу или ненужное подключу. И еще: как обращаясь к $mail->addAddress прописать не статичный адрес получателя, а обратиться к переменной, такое возможно вообще?
И вот еще что - возможно ли реализовать отправку форм с локального сервера через xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с phpmailer 6.0.2 подключать должно файл `PHPMailer.php`. И, к стати, они начали использовать `namespace`.

Отправка нескольким получателям:

```
$recipients = array(
    "mail@to.one",
    "mail@to.two"
);
...
foreach($recipients as $recipient){
    ...
     $mail->AddAddress($recipient);
    ...
    $mail->Send();
}
```